# Smart way to not kill WebService

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, cocoa-touch, delegates

It's my code :

```
for (FlightScopePlayerPlayer *player in self.selectedPlayers) {
BaseballPlayer_GetBaseballProfileRequest *re = [[BaseballPlayer_GetBaseballProfileRequest alloc]initWithPlayerID:player.ID];
            [bseModel.myFlightScopeClient.baseballPlayerServiceClient GetBaseballProfile:re
                                                                             onCompleted:^(id response) {
                                                                                 BaseballPlayer_GetBaseballProfileResponse *res = (BaseballPlayer_GetBaseballProfileResponse *)response;
self.player = res.player;
[self.baseballPlayerList addObject:self.player];
[DelegateHelper performProtocol:@protocol(LoadPlayersFromWSModelCallbackDelegate)
                                                                                                      withTarget:self.delegates
                                                                                                    withSelector:@selector(isResponseRedyToUseAfterGetProfile:)
                                                                                                    withArgument:self];
```

This construction can kill my `webservice`. What is the smarter way to send this? The idea is that in array are objects and i want to send request for everyone but if in the array will be 1000 objects `Webservice` can die so my idea is send request when the previous is finished and send delegate at the end.

Comment: you should be able to send 1 request to the server with a list of ids and have the server send 1 response back... your current code probably floods the network rather than breaking the webservice

Comment: This webservice is created that at the input gets exactly 1 ID. I cant send e.x array of id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd have a different webservice.

Assuming you can't change, you need to queue your requests so you don't make too many at any one time and you can suspend processing if required. Potentially you can also retry failed requests by adding them back on to the end of the queue.

`NSOperationQueue` is appropriate for this. You can use `NSBlockOperation` to contain your processing logic to call the webservice. Be sure to set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to some value between 1 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RQOperation](https://github.com/nicklockwood/RequestQueue)

Basically the idea is to store the web API calls in an array and then you can execute them in serial manner. (Once the previous is complete, execute the next one)

It has nice sample within. Hope that helps.

Not enough reps to post as comment, hence answer.